# Procedure to quickly find the near zero eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors) of a positive semidefinite square matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

I have an ill-conditioned positive semidefinite $n \times n$ square matrix (Hessian), with unknown rank $r$, that I need to compute the inverse for. I'd prefer not to compute the SVD for performance reasons. There's a trick I've read about to solve this, if I can first compute only the zero or near-zero eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors). Specifically, I only need the smallest $(n-r)$ eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors). However, it is unclear to me how to efficiently obtain just this subset of eigenvalues. Can I use QR decomposition somehow? I'd appreciate if someone is able to outline a relatively efficient procedure.

**Update**

The trick is called Epsilon Decomposition (E-D) and is outlined in this paper: *"Interpretation and solution of ill-conditioned equations arising in parameter estimation and system identification"* (Ojalvo 1990). With the proper epsilon value, the technique is easy and allows the inversion of ill-conditioned Hessians even using fast LU (for example). But picking the proper epsilon systematically is what requires more math and motivates my question.

Comment: Use Cholesky, $LDL^T$, it works with PSD and it is faster than QR. Do you really need the inverse or you want to solve a system? Can you please give a reference to the trick you mention?

Comment: @usεr11852 I've updated my question to provide more details.  Would $LDL^T$ decomposition work with a range of ranks $r$ (actual rank would vary somewhat between different calculations)? Also how do I get the eigenvalues out, is it just $D$?